# How to statistically plot and show the difference between two fluctuations

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This is kind of a tricky question.So if you cannot understand kindly do post comments.

This is a data between an Anchor and source with their dBm values.

If you see the first set of data it is between A=30,S=50 and you can see the fluctuation in the dBm values in different channels. Taking average of all these 4 channel combinations will give us -72.75

```
 **A = 30  S = 50** ,   A-S Distance =  18.00

 The rssi value  with A-Chan 0 and S-Chan 0 is  -69
 The rssi value  with A-Chan 0 and S-Chan 1 is  -73
 The rssi value  with A-Chan 1 and S-Chan 0 is  -73
 The rssi value  with A-Chan 1 and S-Chan 1 is  -76
```

Now the next case is as follows

In this case it is the reverse of the above (i.e.) A=50,S=30. You can see the fluctuations between all the channels and the average dBm value will be  -74.75

```
 **A = 50  S = 30** ,   A-S Distance =  18.00

 The rssi value  with A-Chan 0 and S-Chan 0 is  -74
 The rssi value  with A-Chan 0 and S-Chan 1 is  -77
 The rssi value  with A-Chan 1 and S-Chan 0 is  -73
 The rssi value  with A-Chan 1 and S-Chan 1 is  -75
```

now,if you see in "A=30,S=50"the dBm value is "-72.75" and in "A=50,S=30" dBm value of "-74.75". So there is a fluctuation or difference between these two values.

My question is I want to plot these two statistical plot or in a graph plot showing the difference between them.

How can this be done ?

Do you have any suggestions on how can this be done statistically ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Anybody to answers this ??

Comment: You haven't indicated what kind of statistical plot you want to produce. Do you want a histogram? A box plot? What?

Comment: @wakjah My mistake. I would go with histogram to plot these !! that's a fine solution.

Comment: Have a look at the [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function. The second argument allows you to specify the number of bins (bars in the histogram), or their centres.